# Problen add dependency android studio

Tags: maven, dependencies, artifactory

I posted my library in Artifactory

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/806x253q90/631/kkK1Yn.png

this is my Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle',    
    version: '3.0.1')
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
       url 'http://myartifactory:8081/artifactory/gradle-local'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.2'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
    }

}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.so'], dir: 'libs')
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
   compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
   compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
   compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
   compile 'it.sephiroth.android.exif:library:+'
   compile 'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.8'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
   compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0'
   compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.0.1@aar'
   apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
   compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
   compile(group: 'com.mylibrary.android.common', name: 'android.common', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar')
}
apt {
   arguments {
      androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile

      resourcePackageName 'com.mypackage.library'


   }
}
```

I get this error

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/519x72q90/540/8ojerK.png

Gradle I found that running the route using the url wrong use "/" instead of "."

Try to find

...8081/artifactory/repo/com/mypackage/android/common/android.common/1.0.0/android.common-1.0.0.aar

but should be

...8081/artifactory/repo/com.mypackage.android.common/android.common/1.0.0/android.common-1.0.0.aar

I'm doing wrong, wrong as was published in the artefactory

Answer (score 1):

Your artifact is not complaint to the standard Maven layout, in which the groupId should be separated by `/`, not by `.`.

It's not a big deal, Gradle can handle it easly, you just can't declare the repository as `maven`, but as `ivy` instead.

Actually, it will be easier to use [the `artifactory` plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) for resolution, it also supports both Maven and Ivy layouts.

Also, please remember to set the [repository in Artifactory to be with correct layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) (not Maven2, probably Ivy).

And frankly, I think maybe it worth redeploying the artifact under Maven layout, it will make your life easier.